# Path to Universal User's Library/Color Folder?

Tags: macos, path, pkgbuild

I'm building a package that installs a `.clr` file into a user's `library/color` folder. The problem is that the following path:

```
~/Library/Colors/
```

results in creating a new folder on their macs with my computer's name and the clr. file inside that.

If I use

```
./Library/Colors/
```

Then it just stores it in the Main Library folder in the Macintosh HD folder. Or is this the right folder if I want it appearing for all users on a mac?

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `~/Library/Colors/` is resulting in your computer's name when running the package on different systems, that means that the `'~'` got resolved while you created the package.
As an alternative, you can try

```
/Users/\$USER/Library/Colors/
```